# Materialize collection secondary bottom not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to align a button properly as a secondary content within a collection. However, no matter what I try, I cannot get the button centered. See image below:

[Current Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCowm.png)

Code snippet:

```html
<div class="section">
  <ul class="collection with-header">
    <li class="collection-header">
      <h5>Drawing basics</h5>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <div>Public Policy and the Community<a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">delete</i><a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">edit</i><a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i></a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">

      <div> Introduction to Geology Studies
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right"> Create
    
                    </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      <div> Global Perspective<a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">delete</i><a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">edit</i><a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i></a></div>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

What can I do to solve this? I've tried almost everything.

Comment: provide css snipet...

Comment: @amit77309 Hi! I'm using the css framework MaterializeCSS as indicated within the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Well I couldn't get it to work as I'd like to but it works with this hardcode....

```
.fix{
  float: right;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ggcewqaL/2/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is a bit late but here is the fix without the need for an additional CSS class.

```
  <ul class="collection with-header">
      <li class="collection-header"><h4>Drawing basics</h4></li>
      <li class="collection-item"><div>Public Policy and the Community<a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="">remove_red_eye</i></a></div></li>
      <li class="collection-item">
          <div>Introduction to Geology Studies
              <a href="#!" class="waves-effect waves-light btn  secondary-content">Create</a>
              </a>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item"><div>Global Perspective<a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i></a></div></li>
  </ul>
```

I just added an anchor tag inside the second div and styled it with .btn class

```
<a href="#!" class="waves-effect waves-light btn  secondary-content">Create</a>
```

I hope this would be helpful for someone at least!